# The OUT message was not received within

Tags: apache-camel

Am trying out the JMS example bundled with Apache Camel

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("camel-config.xml");

producer)
ProducerTemplate camelTemplate = context.getBean("camelTemplate", ProducerTemplate.class);

System.out.println("Invoking the multiply with 22");
int responseData = (Integer)camelTemplate.sendBody("jms:queue:numbers", ExchangePattern.InOut, 22);
System.out.println("... the result is: " + responseData);
```

This is the code. This works perfectly when I run in as a standalone application.

The same thing I just put in a servlet and tried running it. I got this error
**The OUT message was not received within**

Comment: The setup is a bit complex in the example. Please provide info on how you set the server part up in a servlet. Have you looked at the errors in the servlet log? try enable some more logging detail - it should be pretty clear if the route starts or not. (http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-enable-debug-logging.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was really a Blunder I made.

Thought of deleting the question. But many might do the same mistake

```
camelTemplate.sendBody("jms:queue:numbers", ExchangePattern.InOut, 22);
```

The problem was with the above line. Am passing 22 as parameter which is an Integer, but the real method in the JSM was receiving a InputStream as argument.

When I changed it , the problem got resolved.